# Android/IOS vs Java

Tags: java, android, ios

Suponhamos que eu tenha um aplicativo em android ou ios

Eu tenho um sistema feito em java ee para publicar dados que serão baixados da internet pelo aplicativo. Tudo isso está dentro de um servidor web

Como procedo essa comunicação entre sistema e aplicativo?

- Faço requisições HTTP diretamente no servidor?
- Construo um webservice para comunicar sistema e app?

Não tenho conhecimentos em desenvolvimento em nenhuma das linguagens, quero apenas compreender como funciona o desenvolvimento na teoria

Comment: Se entendi o que você disse, recomendo ler sobre REST.

Comment: Vou simplificar, suponhamos que tem um app que precisa baixar um xml, com informações sobre localização das lojas. Esse xml é alterado por um outro sistema em java. Qual é a forma correta de baixar esse xml pro aplicativo? faço uma requisição diretamente no servidor, ou crio um webservice que peça para o java entregar o arquivo xml diretamente para o aplicativo.

Comment: Então André, vou tentar ser mais claro, se pesquisou sobre REST (ou RESTful) vai entender que ele é um sistema também de transporte de dados entre diferentes plataformas e servidores. Isto provavelmente vai lhe ajudar a principio, entendeu?

Comment: Compreendo como funciona um webservice, a pergunta é mesmo sobre o dia-a-dia de desenvolvimento. Se preciso comunicar um aplicativo e um sistema na prática isso se faz por meio de webservices, ou normalmente se utiliza uma forma de comunicação mais simples como requisições HTTP

Comment: O REST é comunicação HTTP e o intuito dele é totalmente este, portar dados para múltiplos servidores e/ou plataformas. Podem existir outras maneiras, como o SOAP, mas ainda sim é HTTP. Você não precisa usar o REST em amplitude, ou melhor dizendo, todos métodos, usando o básico POST, PUT e GET vai atingir o seu objetivo. O intuito do REST é apenas padronizar e em alguns casos aumentar a segurança através de tokens. Digo isto, pois geralmente frameworks java para web já tem suporte REST com autenticação e tokens. Sim as requisições podem ser no servidor, mas prese pela segurança, usando tokens..

Comment: **[editado]**... E sim um webservice vai lhe auxiliar não só com APPs mas também se precisar portar os dados para sites e ou plataformas que não sejam suas, se for fazer uma parceria por exemplo. :) - O que vai depender saber aqui é qual framework web usa, seria o jsp?

Comment: Antes de terminar, se não for atrapalhar, qual framework web usa, seria o jsp?

Comment: Sim é o JSP....

Comment: Legal, se até a noite ninguém responder eu tento formular uma resposta mais completa :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resumidamente, o ideal é você criar uma **API REST** e um padrão de representação de dados para que tanto o seu aplicativo mobile quanto a sua aplicação possam compartilhar as informações entre si. Essas informações podem ser representadas utilizando-se JSON, pois a maioria das linguagens possuem bibliotecas para ler e escrever arquivos JSON, além disso ele é bem mais leve que XML.

Para informações sobre como implementar correntamente uma API REST, dê uma olhada [neste link](http://mark-kirby.co.uk/2013/creating-a-true-rest-api/) ( em inglês)